# How to secure Netty connection?

Tags: java, security, encryption, netty

I am trying to secure a Netty Connection, but I have no Idea, what I have to do, to secure it.

Since I do not know how to do this with Netty 5.0 Alpha2, and Google obfuscates me more than it helps, I ask this question here...

Comment: [Setting Up SSL with Netty](https://maxrohde.com/2013/09/07/setting-up-ssl-with-netty/)

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `SslHandler` into the `ChannelPipeline`. There are multiple examples in the netty repositories doing exactly this.

Also you should switch a stable version of netty, like the latest 4.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own authentication logic / Lager in the handler and add it to the beginning of your pipeline as an inbound handler to provide security to your application.